# With a gzip dataframe, how can I read/decompress this line by line?

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, dataframe, gzip

I have an extremely large dataframe saved as a `gzip` file. The data also needs a good deal of manipulation before being saved.

One could try to convert this entire gzip dataframe into text format, save this to a variable, parse/clean the data, and then save as a `.csv` file via `pandas.read_csv()`. However, this is extremely memory intensive.

I would like to read/decompress this file line by line (as this would be the most memory-efficient solution, I think), parse this (e.g. with regex `re` or perhaps a `pandas` solution) and then save each line into a pandas dataframe.

Python has a `gzip` library for this:

```
with gzip.open('filename.gzip', 'rb') as input_file:
    reader = reader(input_file, delimiter="\t")
    data = [row for row in reader]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

However, this seems to drop all information into the 'reader' variable, and then parses. How can one do this in a more (memory) efficient manner?

Should I be using a different library instead of `gzip`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what do you want to do with your huge GZIP file. IIUC you can't read the whole data into memory, because your GZIP file is huge. So the only option you have is to process your data in chunks.

Assuming that you want to read your data from the GZIP file, process it and write it to compressed HDF5 file:

```
hdf_key = 'my_hdf_ID'
cols_to_index = ['colA','colZ'] # list of indexed columns, use `cols_to_index=True` if you want to index ALL columns
store = pd.HDFStore('/path/to/filename.h5')
chunksize = 10**5
for chunk in pd.read_csv('filename.gz', sep='\s*', chunksize=chunksize):
    # process data in the `chunk` DF

    # don't index data columns in each iteration - we'll do it later
    store.append(hdf_key, chunk, data_columns=cols_to_index, index=False, complib='blosc', complevel=4)

# index data columns in HDFStore
store.create_table_index(hdf_key, columns=cols_to_index, optlevel=9, kind='full')
store.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps extract your data with `gunzip -c`, pipe it to your Python script and work with standard input there:

```
$ gunzip -c source.gz | python ./line_parser.py | gzip -c - > destination.gz
```

In the Python script `line_parser.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Replace `sys.stdout.write(line)` with code to process each line in your custom way.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in an automated fashion. Input gzip, output formatted data into .csv (or other type) of file.

Comment: The automation is in the line I suggested replacing. That's where you put your logic. I just gave you an example where you write out the line as it comes in, but you can replace that with whatever logic you need — convert it to CSV, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [HDFStore](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5):

> HDFStore is a dict-like object which reads and writes pandas using the high performance HDF5 format using the excellent PyTables library. See the cookbook for some advanced strategies

**Create Store, save DataFrame and close store.**

```
# Note compression.
store = pd.HDFStore('my_store.h5', mode='w', comp_level=9, complib='blosc')
with store:
    store['my_dataframe'] = df
```

**Reopen store, retrieve dataframe and close store.**

```
with pd.HDFStore('my_store.h5', mode='r') as store:
    df = store.get('my_dataframe')
```

Comment: Does not answer the question, does it? This provides an alternate way to store the data, but not a way to read the file from a gzip file so as to not fill up the memory completely.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still have this 'gzip' file to deal with---unless there's a simpler way to parse the gzip file and store into HDF5 like you detail above. Please tell me fi this is the case I appreciate the help though!